# Is this function free from race-conditions?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I wrote a function which returns me a record ID which is in the PENDING state (the column `state`). And it should limit active downloads (records that are in states STARTED or COMPLETED). So, it helps me to avoid resource limits problems. The functions is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION start_download(max_run INTEGER) RETURNS INTEGER
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS
$$
DECLARE
  started_id INTEGER;
BEGIN

  UPDATE downloads SET state='STARTED' WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id FROM downloads WHERE state='PENDING' AND (
      SELECT max_run >= COUNT(id) FROM downloads WHERE state::TEXT IN ('STARTED','COMPLETED'))
  LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE)
  RETURNING id INTO started_id;

RETURN started_id;
COMMIT;
END;
$$;
```

Is it safe in the meaning of race-conditions? I mean that the resources limit will not be hit because of race condition (2 or more threads will get ID of some PENDING record or even of the same record and the limit of active, i.e. STARTED/COMPLETED downloads will be reached).
In short this function should work as test-and-set procedure and to return the available ID (switched from PENDING to STARTED, but it's irrelevant details). Does it have such property - free from race conditions? Or maybe I have to use some locks...

PS. 1) `downloads` table has columns `id`, `state` (an enum with values like STARTED, PENDING, ERROR, COMPLETED, PROCESSED) and others that don't matter for the question's context. 2) `max_run` is the limit of active downloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a race condition in the innermost subquery.

If two concurrent sessions run your function at the same time, they both could find that `max_run` is equal to the count of started or completed jobs, and they would both start a job, thereby pushing the number of started or running jobs over the limit.

That is not easy to avoid, unless you lock all the started or completed jobs (very bad for concurrency) or use a higher transaction isolation level (`SERIALIZABLE`).

Comment: is it possible to use `pg_advisory_lock()` after `BEGIN` (and `pg_advisory_unlock()` before `COMMIT` as a solution ?

Comment: Yes. That would be equivalent to locking all the rows. It would serialize access to the function and impact concurrency, but it would work.